# Python old values reappearing

Tags: python, sql, recursion

I was set a challenge after I told somebody I exported a dictionary to a database (simple python script to export the OPTED dictionary HTML pages into a database), it was to convert space-less Morse code into a word.

e.g.
Normally messages would be: `.- .--. .--. .-.. .` (apple), with a space in between each character.
But since there is a database to check every possibility against, the new input would be: `.-.--..--..-...` (apple), without the spaces in between.

I wrote a python script to do this, but I found a very odd phenomena, old values (which aren't stored in any variable) are coming up again.

Code is below:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('english_dictionary.db')
c = conn.cursor()

#Morse code alphabet
mc = {'.-' : 'a', '-...' : 'b', '-.-.' : 'c', '-..' : 'd', '.' : 'e', '..-.' : 'f', '--.' : 'g', '....' : 'h', '..' : 'i', '.---' : 'j', '-.-' : 'k', '.-..' : 'l', '--' : 'm', '-.' : 'n', '---' : 'o', '.--.' : 'p', '--.-' : 'q', '.-.' : 'r', '...' : 's', '-' : 't', '..-' : 'u', '...-' : 'v', '.--' : 'w', '-..-' : 'x', '-.--' : 'y', '--..' : 'z'}

#Recursive function - input, current words, current index, current_word
def magic(inp, curwords=[''], curindex=0, current_word=''):
    #print 'inp: "%s", curwords = %s, curindex = %i, current_word = "%s"' % (inp, str(curwords), curindex, current_word)
    #If the function is being called with an empty input, then this word has been finished, so set it up for a new one
    if inp == "":
        curwords.append('')
        curindex += 1
        return curwords,curindex
    #Finding valid Morse code letters
    for i in range(1, len(inp)+1):
        #print 'Current: %i in (1, %i)' % (i, len(inp)+1)
        if inp[:i] in mc:
            #print 'Morse Code: "%s" -> %s in (1, %i)' % (inp[:i],mc[inp[:i]], len(inp)+1)
            curwords[curindex] = current_word + mc[inp[:i]]
            curwords,curindex = magic(inp[i:], curwords, curindex, current_word + mc[inp[:i]])
        #else:
            #print 'Not Morse Code: "%s" in (1, %i)' % (inp[:i], len(inp)+1)
    return curwords,curindex

while 1:
    x = raw_input('> ')
    mag = magic(x)[0]
    for row in c.execute('SELECT DISTINCT word FROM dictionary WHERE LOWER(word) IN %s' % (str(tuple(mag)))):
        print row[0]
```

(Please ask if you want part of the code explained more in-depth)

The problem:

If I input `..-` it returns `It`

If I input `--.` it returns `Me`

(Both of which are correct)

However if I do `.-.--..--..-...` it returns `Apple` (again, correct but here is where it breaks)

Now, if I do any morse code after I check `Apple`, then `Apple` is returned as a result.

e.g.

(Run these in order)

`> ..-` -> `It`

`> --.` -> `Me`

`> .-.--..--..-...` -> `Apple`

`> ..-` -> `Apple, It`

`> --.` -> `Apple, Me`

I made it output `mag` before the SQL statement, and it has all the possibilities that apple has + the possibilities of the new input (therefor its not caused by SQL).

I have tried adding `mag = []` at the end of the `while` loop, and still doesn't work.

I had experienced odd behavior similar to this in a different language which was caused by modifying the value of arguments parsed into a function, so I tried copying the values to new variables, but to no avail.

Comment: At a quick glance, `curwords=['']` looks dangerous to me. For more info, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: @Kevin Thanks, that seems to be the problem, I'm looking further into it because from a preliminary check, there are inconsistencies (ie, only "apple" causes the problem, "it" and "me" don't 'stick around')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python default arguments are only evaluated once. When you append to a list that was a default argument (like `curwords`) the default argument will be changed in subsequent calls to the function.

If you want to get an empty list automatically whenever you call the function without supplying `curwords`, try something like:

```
def magic(curwords=None):
  if curwords is None: curwords = []
  # ...
```

For more information, refer to [Default Argument Values](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values) in the Python language tutorial.